# modifying csv file using vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I need help in modifying the CSV file using VBA. I did research and came up with this solution. However, I can't get the expected output. So, for example, I have a CSV file:

```
ProductID,ProductName,SupplierName,CategoryID,Unit,Price
,,,,,
1,Chais,John Ray,1,10 boxes x 20 bags,18.00093483
2,Chang,Michael,1,24 - 12 oz bottles,19.66890343
```

I want to change all the values under the `productname` and `suppliername`. And change something like the combination of ProductID and the Column Name. My expected output should look like:

```
    ProductID,ProductName,SupplierName,CategoryID,Unit,Price
,,,,,
1,1 ProductName,1 SupplierName,1,10 boxes x 20 bags,18.00093483
2,2 ProductName,2 SupplierName,1,24 - 12 oz bottles,19.66890343
```

It can occur multiple times and can change the column location. This is my code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim FilePath As String, LineFromFile As Variant, LineItems() As String, strFile As Variant
    FilePath = "C:\Users\mestrivo\Documents\Files\MyFirstProg\test.csv"
    Open FilePath For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        LinteItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
        LineItems(1) = LineItems(0) & " ProductName"
        LineItems(2) = LineItems(0) & " SupplierName"
        strFile = Join(LineItems, ",")
    Loop

    Open "C:\Users\mestrivo\Documents\Files\MyFirstProg\test - 2.csv" For Output As #1

    Print #1, strFile
    Close #1

End Sub
```

Please help me check my code. I got an error on this part:

```
Open "C:\Users\mestrivo\Documents\Files\MyFirstProg\test - 2.csv" For Output As #1
```

it says that the file is already open.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: `LinteItems` - use `Option Explicit`  !

Comment: @TimWilliams, i am already using option explicit.

Comment: @urdearboy, i modified my question.

Comment: Then why are you not seeing a compile error?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I got an error on this part Open "C:\Users\mestrivo\Documents\Files\MyFirstProg\test - 2.csv" For Output As #1, it says that the file is already open.

Comment: `strFile` only contains the content for the last line, since you overwrite it every time through the loop...  You need to open the output file before you enter the loop, then write out each modified line as the loop progresses.

Comment: @TimWilliams may I know, what should I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim FilePath As String, LineFromFile As Variant, _
    LineItems() As String, strFile As Variant

    FilePath = "mycsv.csv"
    Open FilePath For Input As #1

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        LineItems() = Split(LineFromFile, ",")

        'I suggest to add the following 'If' statements
        If LineItems(0) <> "" Then
            LineItems(1) = LineItems(0) & " ProductName"
            LineItems(2) = LineItems(0) & " SupplierName"
        End If

        If strFile <> "" Then strFile = strFile & Chr(10)
        '-------------------------------------------------

        strFile = strFile & Join(LineItems, ",")
    Loop

    'In the next 'Open' statement you are trying to
    'assign an object over another that's already opened,
    'therefore you must close the previous object first
    'and / or declare the second one with another name
    Close #1
    Open "mycsv2.csv" For Output As #1
    Print #1, strFile
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Ferd, i just realized what if there is a comma in the input file? How do i ignore it if Im going to use the comma when splitting the data?

Comment: Three options here:
• Deal with those cases directly from `LineFromFile` variable, before splitting.
• Make sure your files to not have that condition.
• Use another separator, maybe `|`.

Answer (score 2):

NEVER hard-code file handles, they aren't for you to grab, they're for VBA to query what's available and *give you* a free, usable file handle. Use the `FreeFile` function to do this.

```
Dim fileHandle As Long
fileHandle = FreeFile
```

Then replace all hard-coded `#1` handles with `#fileHandle`.

You cannot open two different files using the same handle. You've already opened the file for input:

```
Open FilePath For Input As #1
```

So when you try to use the same handle for output...

```
Open "C:\Users\mestrivo\Documents\Files\MyFirstProg\test - 2.csv" For Output As #1
```

That's when you get an error; you haven't closed the `#1` handle yet, and now you're trying to reuse it to open another file - you can't do that.

You're dealing with two files, so either you open the first one, read it, *then close it* before you open the second one, write to it and then close it - or, you open both, and write to one as you read the other, then close both.

Either way, you shouldn't hard-code file handles. Use `FreeFile` to get a free file handle. Always.